# OData Web API, Register a function for a collection

Tags: c#, function, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a Web API application where I have hooked up my Entityframework-context as the datasource and I'm using OData to "expose" my data.

However I need a custom function for my API called "WithInRange" that will take three parameters:
* Longitude:float
* Latitude:float
* Range:float

```
public IQueryable<MyObject> WithInRange([FromODataUri] float longitude, float latitude, float range){
//DO STUFF
}
```

So basically what I would like to be able to do is to trigger the above "function/action" with the following url ~/odata/MyObjects/WithInRange(Longitude=11.12,Latitude=12.32,Range=1000)

And that would then retrive an array with all MyObjects thats with in that range.

However.. I cant really figure out how to do this..
Could someone please provide me with a brief working example?
I think that my main problem is that I dont really get how to register this against my ODataConventionModelBuilder-object...

Any ideas?

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 0):

This [sample](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-06-function-parameter-support) is suitable for you I think, you can follow the sample step by step, any issue can report to odatafeedback@microsoft.com :).